# ACF Создать поле которое может редактировать только админ

Tags: wordpress, acf

Скажите, есть ли возможность создать в админки поле плагина [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) типа Текст, редактирование значения которого в админке будет возможно только для пользователей ранга администратор? Поле для вкладки `Users/Profile`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал вот так. Через добавление в `functions.php`

```
function acf_field_read_only( $field ) {
    $field['readonly'] = ! current_user_can('manage_options');
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'acf/load_field/name=user_rank', 'acf_field_read_only' );
```

Но, тут если пользователь заходит в DevTools и правит значение `value` данного поля, а потом всё сохраняет, то у него всё изменяется. И как этот баг обойти не понятно.

[image: ReadOnly]

Comment: Ну как вариант, можно зацепиться за фильтр [acf/update_value](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-update_value/) и проверять, может ли пользователь его обновлять или нет, так же можно провернуть что-то подобное например на [acf/save_post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) c приоритетом 5 (то есть до того, как данные будут сохранены в БД), по идее можно еще варианты найти.

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно создать поле типа Текст в плагине ACF, которое может быть редактировано только пользователями с рангом администратора. Для этого можно использовать фильтр acf/load_field, как вы уже пробовали, и проверять роль пользователя с помощью функции current_user_can().

Чтобы обойти баг, который вы описали, можно добавить дополнительную проверку на стороне сервера при сохранении значения поля. Например, можно использовать хук acf/update_value и проверять роль пользователя перед сохранением значения, если роль не соответствует администратору, вернуть предыдущее значение и выдать сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Могли бы вы показать как бы выглядел конечный результат? ACF тестового поля прилагаю https://fex.net/ru/s/x9ltotf

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете запретить пользователям редактировать значение поля, используя для поля атрибут "readonly". Однако, как вы упомянули, это можно обойти, отредактировав значение в инструментах разработчика браузера. Чтобы предотвратить это, вы можете использовать проверку на стороне сервера, чтобы проверить, есть ли у пользователя правильные разрешения, прежде чем обновлять значение поля.

Вот пример того, как вы можете сделать это с помощью плагина Advanced Custom Fields (ACF):

```
function acf_validate_user_rank($valid, $value, $field, $input) {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
add_filter('acf/validate_value/name=user_rank', 'acf_validate_user_rank', 10, 4);
```

Этот код добавляет фильтр проверки для поля "user_rank", который проверяет, есть ли у текущего пользователя возможность "manage_options" (которая обычно предоставляется только администраторам). Если у пользователя нет этой возможности, проверка завершится ошибкой и значение поля не будет обновлено.

Важно отметить, что эта проверка работает только на стороне сервера, а проверку на стороне клиента все еще можно обойти с помощью инструментов браузера.

Comment: Вместо добавления нового ответа, наверное имело бы смысл отредактировать Ваш предыдущий ответ, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1489114/edit)

Comment: Так, собственно и интересовало как производиться добавление хука 'acf/update_value' для проверки роль пользователя перед сохранением значения, если роль не соответствует администратору?